# Misdirected redirect with 3 domains on EV SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, cpanel, http2

**Error**:

```
The client needs a new connection for this request as the requested host name does not match the Server Name Indication (SNI) in use for this connection.
```

I recently purchased a EV SSL certificate from Comodo, installed it on my VPS (cPanel/WHM) and everything worked great. I then upgraded to http2 and am now receiving the error when switching between each website on the certificate. The 3 websites share the same IP address. From what I can tell, this may be the issue. I do not want to reissue a SSL cert for each domain as I paid for the EV multi domain cert. Is the answer to purchase 2 additional IPs and make sure each domain has its own IP? Or is there a way I can edit  the virtual hosts so that I can maintain the same setup I have now?

I should mention, this is only happening on Safari, not chrome.

**SSL Labs Report**

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.deschutesdesigngroup.com&s=142.4.0.142&hideResults=on

**EasyApache HTTP vhost configuration**

https://pastebin.com/dNeFRGWJ

**EasyApache HTTPS vhost configuration**

https://pastebin.com/vgWAD5mg

Comment: What’s the error? Did downgrading from http2 fix it again? Did you run your site(s) through https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to see if set up correctly?

Comment: @BarryPollard I've updated the question with the error and the SSL Labs report.

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled HTTP/2 on only two of the three sites.

HTTP/2 will try to reuse the connection for multiple domains if both the IP address matches and the certificate covers all the necessary domains. This is the case here and so HTTP/2 is reused.

However if you run SSLLabs on all three domains you see a slight difference in the protocol used for Chrome (for example):

```
Chrome 70 / Win 10  RSA 2048 (SHA256)   TLS 1.2 > h2  
Chrome 70 / Win 10  RSA 2048 (SHA256)   TLS 1.2 > http/1.1  
Chrome 70 / Win 10  RSA 2048 (SHA256)   TLS 1.2 > h2
```

And similarly further down in the ALPN setting:

```
ALPN    Yes   h2 http/1.1
ALPN    Yes   http/1.1
ALPN    Yes   h2 http/1.1
```

So going to the middle domain first will work as it will connect via HTTP/1.1 and so not reuse the connection. However going to the middle domain after initiating a request to either the first or last domain will attempt to reuse the HTTP/2 connection and fail as the middle domain doesn't support HTTP/2.

Web servers should return a [`421 Misdirected Request` status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#section-9.1.2) for any requests when the browser attempts to reuse the connection when it shouldn't, to say "Yeah you really shouldn't be attempting to reuse the connection here! Can you try again on another connection please?". The same thing happens if there are different SSL/TLS setup (e.g. the cipher suite used for the connection is not accepted on the other domain).

Chrome and Firefox correctly handle the `421` response and transparently resend the requests over a new connection, which in this case then uses HTTP/1.1 (check out developer tools in the browser and you'll see this is true). Other browsers, including Safari used by iOS, have not implemented support of the relatively new 421 status code yet and so fail with an error like below:

> Misdirected Request
>
> The client needs a new connection for this request as the requested
> host name does not match the Server Name Indication (SNI) in use for
> this connection.

I presume there is no reason not to enable HTTP/2 on all domains and this was a misconfiguration error? If so enable HTTP/2 in all domains and your issue should be sorted.

If you do not want HTTP/2 on all domains, then you ensure the browser doesn't think it can reuse the connection. That means either using a separate IP address for that domain, or getting the certificate reissued for only two domains, and a separate certificate for the other than shouldn't share connections.

Comment: This makes perfect sense. Thank you for the great explanation. I manage the Apache configuration with cPanel and installed HTTP2 with EasyApache. I would have assumed it enabled it for all domains? How can I make sure it is enabled on all 3 domains?

Comment: I presume you may have checked SSL Labs when I turned HTTP2 back off. I have re-enabled it and it appears to be working for each domain as the protocol and ALPN look correct for all 3. I am still receiving the 421 error though.

Comment: Looks better now, but agree it's still giving that error sometimes. Can you give all your SSL vhost config for each domain? Something must be different.

Comment: I've attached the auto generated vhost config by EasyApache to the original post.

Comment: You've included the HTTP vhosts, but not the HTTPS vhosts which is the ones we need to see. Also the fact you are using port 8080 instead of 80 suggests there is something else in front of this Apache (haproxy or some other loadbalancer?). Can you describe how that works - is it terminating HTTPS (so there really is only these vhosts defined in Apache?)? Is it acting like an HTTP or TCP loadbalancer?

Comment: I've got Varnish in front as a reverse proxy for HTTP acceleration. I wonder if this could be the problem if SSL termination is occuring here, instead of Apache? I did a little searching and it sounds like people are using nginx in cooperation with varnish for handling HTTPS as varnish appears to not handle HTTPS.

Comment: So is that where you have enabled HTTP/2 and not in Apache? If so need to see that config.

Comment: No, HTTP2 is enabled in Apache.

Comment: I do not believe Varnish is the issue. It is only listening on port 80. Apache is listening on 443. I have attached the SSL vhosts config above.

Comment: Well, I have fixed the issue. I uninstalled Varnish and installed Nginx as my caching reverse proxy. SSL termination happens at nginx and all requests are then past to Apache over HTTP. Seems to be working great. Thanks for your help. I am using the Engintron cPanel plugin if anyone is curious.